# php sessions from one php page to another

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm new to php sessions and I want to send data from php page to another one. in the first page i have this code:

```
session_start();
$statements="<p>{$actorName} {$verbDisplay} {$objectName}</p>";
$_SESSION['regName'] = $statements;
if(isset($_SESSION['regName']))
{
echo $_SESSION['regName'];
header("Location: http://localhost/moodle/blocks/tincanlrs/downloadlrs.php");
}
```

Here the isset function is returnig true and everything is OK.
In the second page I have this code:

```
session_start();
$statements = $_GET['regName']; 
header("Content-Type: plain/text");
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=lrs_statements.txt");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo $statements;
if (isset($_SESSION['regName']))
{
    echo "session";
}
else
{
    echo "no session";
}
```

Here when I open lrs_statements.txt I have :

**Notice**:  Undefined index: regName in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moodle\blocks\tincanlrs\downloadlrs.php** on line **9**
no session.

Why?? And am I doing something wrong?? Thanks in advance

[edited]
I tested session_start and the session is starting but when I tested session_id() I have different ids and not the same id.
When I add at the top of the second page:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);exit();
```

I have this output: array(0) { }

Comment: you dont need this $statements = $_GET['regName']; 
 try instead echo $_SESSION['regName'];

Comment: why are you reaching $_GET in second page? 
 $statements = $_GET['regName'];

Comment: basic debugging: check the return value of `session_start()`. it'll be boolean false if a session couldn't be started. check the value of `session_id()` in both scripts. If you get different values, then you've got two or more different sessions and are "losing" the value you stored in one of them.

Comment: you shouldn't echo or output anything before header(), (not related to question but I thought I'd mention it)

Comment: at the VERY TOP of the second page put `session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION);exit();` and edit your question with the output

Answer (score 0):

In your second page access your session from $_SESSION like this: $_SESSION['regName'];

$_GET will hold all of the name/value pairs in the request URI, e.g. everything after the ? in the URL

One more thing to note is that if your using isset() to check then you will not get an undefined index error ever.

Answer (score 0):

This line is failing:

```
$statements = $_GET['regName'];
```

Why is it failing? Because this is the URL you are redirecting to on the first page:

```
http://localhost/moodle/blocks/tincanlrs/downloadlrs.php
```

There is no parameter "regName" in this URL, so the access to $_GET will trigger an "undefined index" notice.

And one more thing: On the first page you are echoing back content, and only then you are adding another HTTP header. This usually (with an exception) will fail because using "echo" will send all current headers to the browser and disallow sending more. The exception is when output buffering is turned on, which allows to mix these two outputs, but it is highly recommended not to rely on this feature just in case your code has to run on a host that does not allow switching the output buffers on.

Now the question is: Which one of your lines in the second page is line 9. If I count the lines, I see that `echo "session";` would be line 9, but this does not match with the error message you are getting.

Comment: line 9 is '$statements = $_GET['regName'];'